# How to create <div>'s with items on all page, without scrollbars?

Tags: html, css

I need to create one page with 4 elements: header, filter of elements, item list and item. But i can't to set div's without main page scroll. I want to have only one scroll bar - in `item-list`?

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    background-color: cadetblue;
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
}

.space {
    width: 25em;
    height: 100%;
}

.filter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    background-color: darkblue
}

.item-list {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0.2em;
    overflow: auto;
}

.item {
    background-color: burlywood;
    height: 20em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="space">
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <div class="item-list">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Can anybody to help me with this?

Comment: Answer me this: If you want to remove the page scrollbar, how will users scroll down the page if it's longer than their screen? E.G. with this snippet, i have to scroll down because all the content can't fit in the snippet window.

What your asking to do will render your page unusable for the likes of mobile users.

Comment: but it can be done using `overflow-y: hidden;` (but shouldn't)

Comment: Longer content can be only in item-list(because "item"'s can be many). And i need to have scroll only in it

Comment: @SourceOverflow , yes but some `item`'s will be hidden to, because i can't show it by "item-list" scroll

Comment: Yes? How else would that work? See @ProEvilz's comment

Comment: If your `header` has `3em` height and `space` has `100%` height, you always have a scrollbar, as the total exceeds the full height of the body. You could use `calc()`

Comment: Thank for all. @G-Cyr is found answer. But idea with `calc()` can be alive to, i think. I will try to use it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex and overflow:

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
/* === flex update ====*/
body, .space {/* display:flex and overflow:hidden */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.space, .item-list {/* fill whole space avalaible */
flex:1;
}

.item-list {
    overflow: auto;/* overflow ...*/
    background:gray /* debug, see me */
}

/* === end flex update ====*/

.header {
    background-color: cadetblue;
    height: 3em;
}

.space {
    width: 25em;
}

.filter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5em;
    background-color: darkblue
}

.item-list {
    margin: 0.2em;
}

.item {
    background-color: burlywood;
    height: 20em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
    <div class="space">
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <div class="item-list">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's true. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using Scroll on the main element by setting a static height on your header and using calc on your space element, just like the example..

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}

.header {
    background-color: cadetblue;
    height:20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.space {
    width: 25em;
    height: calc(100% + -30px);
    position:relative;
}

.filter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: darkblue
}

.item-list {
    height: 80%;
    margin: 0.2em;
    overflow: auto;
}

.item {
    background-color: burlywood;
    height: 20em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="space">
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <div class="item-list">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i need to set `filter' with fixed height. But i think, idea with `calc()` is good.

Answer (score 0):

remove overflow:auto from .item-list 
and make the .item class height 100% instead of 20em.

Hope this will full full your requirement.